# No qualifying bean of type for bean in context.xml

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have 2 classes in 2 different packages-

```
package com.foo.pacA.A;
  public class A {

    @Autowired
    private B b;
}
```

with context.xml -

```
<import resource="classpath:/spring/data-seeding-plugin-context.xml" />
    <bean class="com.foo.pacA.A" id="a"/>
```

and pom.xml -

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.foo.pacB</groupId>
        <artifactId>b-pack</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and -

```
 package com.foo.pacB.B;
 public class B {

    private C c;

    public void beforeLoadData(SeedingContext seedingContext) {
        this.c = seedingContext.getBean(C.class);
}
```

class B has a context file data-seeding-plugin-context.xml -

```
<bean class="com.foo.pacB.B" id="b"/>
<bean class="com.foo.pacB.C" id="c"/>
```

[image]

when I'm trying to load the A service - It gives me an error

```
 No qualifying bean of type 'com.foo.pacB.C' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

What am I missing?

Thanks